# Update a todos los nombres de archivos que en su nombre tengan una letra con acento

Tags: mariadb

Tengo una tabla llamadas mdl_files con los siguientes atributos:

> Tabla mdl_files

```
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field           | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id              | bigint(10)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| contenthash     | varchar(40)  | NO   | MUL |         |                |
| pathnamehash    | varchar(40)  | NO   | UNI |         |                |
| contextid       | bigint(10)   | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| component       | varchar(100) | NO   | MUL |         |                |
| filearea        | varchar(50)  | NO   |     |         |                |
| itemid          | bigint(10)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| filepath        | varchar(255) | NO   |     |         |                |
| filename        | varchar(255) | NO   |     |         |                |
| userid          | bigint(10)   | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| filesize        | bigint(10)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| mimetype        | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| status          | bigint(10)   | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| source          | longtext     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| author          | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| license         | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| timecreated     | bigint(10)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| timemodified    | bigint(10)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| sortorder       | bigint(10)   | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| referencefileid | bigint(10)   | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Realice la consulta para traer los registros que cumplan con la condición:

> Consulta que trae algunos registros con acentos en su nombre
> (filename)

```
SELECT *from mdl_files WHERE filename = 'RECURSO 1 ACTIVIDAD 2 COMPROBACIÓN DE TEXTOS DE LECTURA FÁCIL.pdf';
```

Como resultado obtuve 6 registros, pero lo que estoy intentando es realizar un update para sustituir las letras que tienen acento por la letra sin acento.

Una forma muy tediosa podría ser podría ser:

```
UPDATE mdl_files SET filename = 'RECURSO 1 ACTIVIDAD 2 COMPROBACION DE TEXTOS DE LECTURA FACIL.pdf' WHERE filename = 'RECURSO 1 ACTIVIDAD 2 COMPROBACIÓN DE TEXTOS DE LECTURA FÁCIL.pdf'
```

Como podría buscar todos los registros que en su filename tengan una letra Ó (una letra o con acento) para posteriormente hacer el uldapte y sustituir todas las letras que tengan un acento por la misma letra, pero sin acento.

Comment: ¿Que versión de MariaDB esta usando?

Comment: ES LA VERSIÓN 10.5